# Which hardware and software is needed to have the battery status reported to the OS?

Tags: battery, power, acpi

Every smartphone, tablet and laptop does this out of the box independently from the OS. My question is how? Which hardware and software is involved? Which protocols and interfaces? How feasible would it be to have such mechanism reproduced for an external battery pack, such as a DIY UPS connected to a desktop pc?

Could leveraging on open source BIOSes such as coreboot and opensource OS such as linux simplify the task, providing a standard way to do this without having to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You should / could have changed your question from your other posting/question? https://superuser.com/questions/1515178/smart-battery-pack-talking-with-the-the-os it would have made the moderator happier with it all.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What circuitry displays battery status in laptops](https://superuser.com/questions/12701/what-circuitry-displays-battery-status-in-laptops?r=SearchResults&s=3|84.3003)

Comment: Any half decent device has its own software to tell you about its battery. It has been like this for some decades. But you need your own software for Do it yourself UPS. My APC UPS reports on its battery

Comment: @John " It has been like this for some decades" exactly! Is it possible that there is no standard way to do this? Something that leverages on existing machinery already built in open source BIOS (eg coreboot) and OS (eg linux)?

Comment: I have not seen standard software for this, just the software that comes with the device and battery (even if the device is a UPS

Comment: The designer would have to mate the software with the battery

Answer (score 0):

I have found a lot of interesting information on this unix.stackexchange question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317864/how-to-clear-reset-smart-battery-memory

The keywords are SMBus (System Management Bus), and SBS (Smart Battery Specification). They should allow the OS to talk directly to the battery (or at least to get battery info from the BIOS and ACPI) as long as the motherboard exposes an I2C interface and proper monitoring circuitry is implemented.

The linked answer also provides a link to a document containing more details about the battery firmware: https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Miller/BH_US_11_Miller_Battery_Firmware_Public_WP.pdf. Following these rules it should be relative straightforward to have a battery recognized by the OS as the internal one, without the need of going through USB and writing custom drivers, apps and widgets.

Good luck!